# Using GROUP BY clause on nvarchar data type in T-SQL Query

Tags: sql-server, group-by

I am using SQL SERVER 2014. I have a query that stands like this:

```
SELECT [PMSConfirmationNumber],[AR ACCOUNT NAME],sum([FOC NET AMOUNT]) AS [FOC_NET AMOUNT]

 FROM ARACCOUNT
 WHERE [PMSCONFIRMATIONNUMBER] = '81827436-1'
 Group by [PMSConfirmationNumber],[AR ACCOUNT NAME],[FOC NET AMOUNT]
```

However, the PMSCONFIRMATIONNUMBER field being an NVARCHAR data type, I'm having the following output:

```
 PMSConfirmationNumber  AR ACCOUNT NAME          FOC_NET AMOUNT
    81827436-1               TRltd                  1400
    81827436-1               TRltd                   600
```

since I have used SUM(FOC NET AMOUNT) in my initial query, I am after the following output:

```
  PMSConfirmationNumber       AR ACCOUNT NAME        FOC_NET AMOUNT
         81827436-1              TRltd                  2000
```

How do I amend my query? Researching the topic, I've come across the 'PARTITION BY' clause but I'm having some difficulties implementing it in my query.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This has nothing to do with the nvarchar type. The issue is that you include the column you aggregate in the group by clause.

Remove `[FOC NET AMOUNT]` from the group by clause. It shouldn't be there as it is being used in an aggregate function and as such isn't part of the grouping.